# My son went onto a online gaming website called Roblox and now a constant sound is playing

Tags: windows-8

my son has a windows 8 and loves playing on **roblox** and now he has a very annoying sound constantly playing and wont stop, apparently a game "Glitched out" and now this sound is playing. We have gone to task manager and tried turned the game client off and to drain the battery but nothing is working! If anyone has an answer that would be great!

P.S I have checked that no viruses have been detected and that our internet was working and there was a strong enough connection to run **Google Chrome**

Comment: Perform a restart

Comment: That did not work unfortunately, but thank you very much.

Comment: So you restart led the pc and once you logged back into a user a sound was still playing that means it's not software but hardware

Comment: Does that mean I have to perform something major?

Comment: Use the volume mixer to verify if a process is or is not making the sound

Comment: Make sure it is not playing from a microphone. It is very possible this is a feedback loop, and something just turned on the microphone. You can test this by shouting very shortly and see if you hear an echo.

Comment: Also, it would help to tell us what sound you hear exactly. Can you describe the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

- Go to the Task Manager -> Startup tab -> Disable startups for unrecognized programs (see something related to robolox is there or not), Then restart your system.
- If sound is still on, open services (In run command box type 'services.msc'), search for something related to robolox there (e.g. robolox player). Open its properties -> stop the service and disable it.
- If sound is turning on after google chrome is opened, Go to addons/plugins and remove plugin/addon related to robolox. OR reinstall google chrome.